# Dynamics CRM : JavaScript onClick Function for Date change

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I'm still pretty new to JavaScript, so I could use a little assistance with this requirement.

I have two HTML webresource buttons setup at the top of a form (new_dayPagePreviousButton and new_dayPageNextButton), and between them is a calendar field (new_daypagedate).  We have subgrids on the page configured to return results depending on the date chosen in the calendar field.

The requirement is to have a single day added or subtracted from the calendar field whenever a user clicks the Previous Day or Next Day button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that field `new_daypagedate` is having Data Type **Date and Time** of Dynamics CRM and `new_dayPagePreviousButton` and `new_dayPageNextButton` are just HTML buttons, and you want that when a user clicks on any of buttons there should be a change in Calendar field of CRM.

As you mentioned that you have created web resource so I am assuming that you have added two buttons and on click event of buttons it should react on `new_daypagedate` field.

Here I have created a web resource for you, please try to apply below javascript in your instance,

```
function AddDays(arg) {
    var d=window.parent.Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_daypagedate").getValue();
    d.setDate(d.getDate() + arg);
    window.parent.Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_daypagedate").setValue(d);
}
```

Optional HTML,

```
<button type="button" id="new_dayPagePreviousButton" onclick="AddDays(-1)">Previous Day</button><br/>
<button type="button" id="new_dayPageNextButton" onclick="AddDays(1)">Next Day</button>
```

Please note, you need to call a javascript function using `onClick` event of a respective button.

SIDE NOTE: As you are using Dynamics CRM, you need to access your CRM
 field using Xrm.Page attribute, you cannot directly access any field
 or HTML tag just by using the id of that field, which you can see in
 above Javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and thorough response Sagar, much appreciated. I'm learning a lot here.

Comment: I created a new webresource on the form, using the Jscript you've given above.  I then edited the 2 existing HTML webresources and replaced the code with the ones you've generously given above.  However, I'm sure I'm missing something here. The buttons aren't triggering the date to change.

Comment: https://ibb.co/NyMN1d5

Link to a screenshot of my form properties, if that helps.  I'm assuming I need to add an Event Handler?

Comment: Pringle, It would be great if you can add the screenshot of your UI, so I can understand How you have added the web resources and what exactly you wanted to do, because as my above javascript you don't need to handle any event handler.

Comment: Form UI: https://ibb.co/CV09FVq
Form Editor: https://ibb.co/yq7MV8f
Form Properties: https://ibb.co/6sgPDnf
'Add Days' Function: https://ibb.co/R2PKPKD
Next Day Button Properties: https://ibb.co/qnrDD6B
Next Day Button Web Resource: https://ibb.co/WFH5XxS
Next Day Button HTML:  https://ibb.co/wMs7MY7

Comment: Kind of banged my head on the desk for not running the debugger yet.  Here's what appears on the console after clicking one of the buttons:

Uncaught ReferenceError: AddDays is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (new_dayPageNextButton:1)
onclick @ new_dayPageNextButton:1

Answer (score 0):

After some additional research, I modified one of the button's HTMLs to include the JScript you had given in your first post Sagar.  It now reads as follows;

```
<html><head>
<script type="text/jscript">
function AddDays(arg) {
var 
d=window.parent.Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_daypagedate").getValue();
d.setDate(d.getDate() + arg);
window.parent.Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_daypagedate").setValue(d);
}
</script>

<meta><style type="text/css">P { margin: 0; }</style><meta><style type="text/css">P { 
margin: 0; }</style></head><body onfocusout="parent.setEmailRange();" 
style="overflow-wrap: break-word;">
<button type="button" id="new_dayPageNextButton" onclick="AddDays(1)">Next 
Day</button>

</body></html>
```

After publishing, the button successfully changes the date!  However once  the date is changed, the subgrids below do not refresh to reflect the new date.  This is a separate issue so I'll post a separate question for it.

Sagar, thanks for walking me through this.  You've been immensely informative.

Comment: Glad to hear that my suggestion worked for you.If you have already created new question regarding subgrid refresh than please share the link of that thread, so I can move my head towards that question.

Comment: I actually got this resolved by putting the following into the script;
window.parent.Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_daypagedate").fireOnChange();

Now, when I click the Next Day or Previous Day buttons, the subgrids refresh and populate the correct results.

Once again, thanks for the continuous support Sagar.  I've learned a lot from this.